# How can I keep the same position on my drop down menu once a user selects a language

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down field on my form. When I select a value from the drop down it immediately resets the focus to the top of the form.

To be clearer I have a drop down menu at the top of the screen and several input fields. The user would have to scroll down to the actual drop down field in order to select it. Once they select the value the page scrolls back to the top.

How can I keep the position the user selected on the form once a user selects a value from the drop down? [NOTE: It will not show up on stack overflow you would have to copy and paste the code and try it on your own browser].

I know it has to do with the

```
  function setValue(){
    document.getElementById("locale").options[value].selected;
    window.location.hash="country-select"; 
  }

  window.onload = setValue;
```

part of my code in my HTML but I don't know what else I need I thought this should make it work. Any help would be appreciated, I just started web development and I'm just self-teaching myself, thank you!

My drop down is setup as:

```js
// creates the page dynamically
function GetSelectedItem(){
  var option = document.getElementById("locale").value;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="languageswitcher.css">
    <script>
      function setValue(){
        document.getElementById("locale").options[value].selected;
        window.location.hash="country-select"; 
      }

      window.onload = setValue;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="country-select">
        <form action="" method = "get">
          <select id= "locale" name="locale">
            <option value="en_US">English(US)</option>
            <option value="en_GB">English(UK)</option>
            <option value="bg_BG">Bulgarian</option>
            <option value="cs_CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="da_DK">Danish</option>
            <option value="de_DE">German</option>
            <option value="ek_GR">Greek</option>
            <option value="es_ES">Spanish</option>
            <option value="et_ET">Estonian</option>
            <option value="fi_FI">Finnish</option>
            <option value="fr_FR">French</option>
            <option value="hu_HU">Hungarian</option>
            <option value="it_IT">Italian</option>
            <option value="lt_LT">Lithuanian</option>
            <option value="lv_LV">Latvian</option>
            <option value="nl_NL">Dutch</option>
            <option value="no_NO">Norwegian</option>
            <option value="pl_PL">Polish</option>
            <option value="pt_PT">Portugese</option>
            <option value="ro_RO">Romanian</option>
            <option value="sk_SK">Slovak</option>
            <option value="sl_SL">Slovenian</option>
            <option value="sv_SE">Swedish</option>
          </select>
          <input value="Select" type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="jquery_1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="languageswitcher.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay I also just would like to say that the console is giving me an error on the windows.onload() function. Why is that?

Comment: @Mosh Feu thanks for beautifying the code haha

Comment: You syntax is invalid. See: http://jsbin.com/woqibo/edit?js

Comment: @MoshFeu  Yes it is I just changed it to

Comment: function setValue(){
            document.getElementById("locale").options[value].selected;
            window.location.hash="country-select"; 
          }
    
    window.onload = setValue;

Comment: But it's giving me an error on [value] on the index of options

Comment: Because you didn't set `value` variable..

Comment: @MoshFeu What should it be set to? Sorry for asking so many questions because I am still self learning, I thought the value variable is already referring to my HTML code for e.g. value = "en_US"?

Comment: I can't see this code in your **script**.

Comment: @MoshFeu those are the only 2 pages I have. I don't have any more javascript code or HTML code